# What are implementations of PRNGs based on ChaCha20?

Tags: random-number-generator, reference-request, chacha

I thought I'd find an implementation in [NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/), but `/dev/urandom` is what I find.  Search engines samples revealed [most implementations are broken](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2014/06/avoid-incorrect-chacha20-implementations.html).

What libraries are there currently?  (I'm only interested in the PRNG based on ChaCha20.)

Comment: Why  not just use OpenSSL?

Comment: OpenBSD is known to implement the arc4random function with ChaCha20 stream cipher. NIST SP 800-90Ar1 specifies HASH_DRBG and HMAC_DRBG that're based on hash functions and keyed-hash message authentication code, which you can instantiate with BLAKE2 hash functions which are in turn based on modified ChaCha PRF.

Comment: The article you link to is a bit puzzling: the author makes a false claim about ChaCha (no, ChaCha is not a block cipher at all), and gives no examples of implementations they claim are ‘incorrect’ or of specific protocols that they implement incorrectly.  Just be clear on what the 384-bit inputs are to ChaCha (key, input/counter) and how you concatenate or carve up the 512-bit outputs, and make sure you have test vectors.

Comment: @DannyNiu, thanks for the pointer.  Indeed, I've been able to verify that `/dev/urandom` is based on ChaCha20 on OpenBSD starting at version 4.5 and NetBSD starting at version 7.0 and has also replaced SHA-1 in the Linux kernel starting at version 4.8.

Comment: @forest, does OpenSSL implement a PRNG based on ChaCha20?  I have not been able to verify this yet --- I'd appreciate pointers to OpenSSL's source code if you know it.

Comment: Now it is a pure reference request, so I can still not reopen it.

Comment: Why can't it be a pure reference request?

Answer (score 3):

Beyond what specific primitive your system will be based on, there are important things to consider while building a CSPRNG.

Bernstein's [Fast-key-erasure random-number generators](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20170723-random.html) article is a good starting point, as well as how randomness generation [is done in Amazon S2N](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/better-random-number-generation-for-openssl-libc-and-linux-mainline/).

Buffer output, but erase data as it's being read, frequently rotate the key, mix multiple entropy sources if possible.

Libsodium provides [a Salsa20-based CSPRNG](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/src/libsodium/randombytes/salsa20/randombytes_salsa20_random.c) implementation. It is not used by default, as for most applications, reading `/dev/urandom` is perfectly fine.

ChaCha20 can be a drop-in replacement for Salsa20 here.

Comment: It's seeded using `/dev/urandom` (or equivalent), and `RDRAND` if available. If you're looking for a deterministic generator, you can simply use ChaCha20 in counter mode.

Comment: Ah, no :-) I was seeking clarification of your answer from the OP's perspective. It's fine.